# MYSQL: ERROR 2027 (HY000): Malformed packet

Tags: mysql, tcpip

No puedo conectar un servidor MySQL de forma remota.
La conexión parece estar bien pues con telnet [ip] [puerta] obtengo respuesta:

```
4.1.3b-beta-nt-max▒@\0v'[uZ,B{efSLa$,Q4N
```

Cuando se ejecuta por línea de comandos o MySQL Workbench 6.3

```
mysql -u[user] -p -h [host]
```

Tengo el mismo error:
**ERROR 2027 (HY000): Malformed packet**

Comment: Pienso que puede ser un problema con max_allowed_packet, aunque serviria mucho si compartieras como tienes la configuración de la conexion en workbench

Comment: Observamos que para esta pregunta, obtuviste una respuesta en SO en ingles. Serias tan amable de copiar esa respuesta, en español, aca, para que futuras personas que busquen tu preguntan tambien encuentren una respuesta? Cuando hagas eso, por favor avisa asi podemos conectar las preguntas con las del sitio en ingles.

Comment: Respuesta a esta pregunta (por el mismo usuario, en ingles): https://stackoverflow.com/q/45654055/73749. Se aceptan traducciones :)